# Enabling Vulkan in Xplane 11/Steam

Tags: linux, fedora, steam, games

So I have two graphic cards, Intel and Nvidia. Xplane also has two versions,

1. OpenGL
2. Vulkan

In steam, when I set

`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia %command%`

I can run XPlane 11 in OpenGL mode by using Nvidia. I know that beacuse when I run `nvidia-smi`, I am getting.

> |    0   N/A  N/A     18819      G   ...X-Plane 11/X-Plane-x86_64       25MiB

which seems that XPlane is using Nvidia Drivers,

However, when I try
`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 %command%`
to run Xplane in Vulkan mode, the game does not seem to use Nvidia since I am getting nothing via `nvidia-smi` command.

So what should I type in Steam Launch Options to run Xplane11 in Nvidia-Vulkan ? Or what could be the cause of the problem...?

I am using Fedora 35 and I have installed vulkan and vulkan-tools. I also have tried
`-vulkan` and `-force-vulkan` commands.